# How to access a file from a stored procedure when that file is on a server in a different domain?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cross-domain

We've run into a bit of a challenge that I'm hoping to get some help with.

We have two windows domains:

- x.local
- prod.x

Here is our issue:

- Our database server (call it prodDB) is in prod.x, and the file is on a server in x.local. There is no trust between these domains.
- We are trying to, from a stored proceedure on prodDB, open a file that is sitting on a file share on x.local. We are running into permission issues.

Is there a way to enable the stored procedure to run in such a way that it can access the file share on that other, non-trusted domain? Assume that we don't want to use SSIS for this.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Try something like this.    EXECUTE xp_cmdshell 'copy c:\\test.csv \\TestServer\\D$\MyFiles\'

Answer (score 0):

So I would first try to isolate the issue. Is it a SQL Server issue or a server issue. Can you remote into the SQL Server server itself and connect to the remote file share using windows explorer? If not then it may be a network/server issue. If yes then likely SQL Server. In that case maybe a SQL CLR solution would meet the need if you can do that. Or call the command line directly using xp_cmdshell to copy the file? I believe both require some level of configuration to enable them.

Is FTP or something similar an option?